# Question about $o$, $O$ and $\sim$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on real line and let $g(x)\ne 0$ from some sufficiently large $x$.

Please let me know if this is correct:

- $f\sim g \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$
- $f=O(g) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$, where $c$ is some positive constant
- $f=o(g) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$

Comment: I thought you could define these for any limit. That is, you could say $f \sim g$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ as well. I could be remembering incorrectly though...

Comment: $f = O(g)$ is $\limsup |f/g| < \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. You should have

- $f\sim g \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=1$
- $f=\Theta(g) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=c$, where $c$ is some positive constant
- $f=O(g) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=c$, where $c$ is some non-negative constant
- $f=o(g) \iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0$

Also, it is not strictly necessary that we take these limits as $x \to \infty$, but that part is context dependent.

Comment: In $f = O(g)$ it is a limsup. And in $f = \Theta(g)$ it is $0 < \liminf \le \limsup < \infty$.